# looking for unique elements in chemical species

Tags: python

Determining unique elements: Write a function which, when given a list of species,
will return an alphabetized list of the unique elements contained in the set of species.
Make use of the parser from the previous step. Example: calling your function with
an input of ['CO', 'H2O', 'CO2', 'CH4'] should return an output of ['C', 'H',
'O']

This is part of a larger project that I am doing.

The problem I am having is how to look at the individual characters of each element. Once I have this I should be able to check if its unique or not. I know this is not right, its just a rough idea of something I am thinking.

```
def unique_elements(x):

    if x in y

    else
    y.append(x)
return y
```

Comment: The question seems to imply that you already have a parser for individual molecules. Probably you want to be calling that for each of the items in the list you are given and combining the results. Can you clarify the question to say what exactly you're having trouble with?

Comment: Are you supposed to use `pyparsing` like in the `chem_compound_parser` example that Prof. Erdmann gave?  (For anyone interested in the context, this is probably one of the final projects in MSE 350 at Arizona -- see [here](http://erg.mse.arizona.edu/mse350/_downloads/balancing_chemical_reactions.pdf) for the full description.  It's worth 30% of the course grade, FWIW.)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def sanitize(compound):
    return compound.translate(None,string.digits)

>>> def elementazie(compoud):
    return re.findall("([A-Z][a-z]*)",compoud)

>>> sorted(set(chain(*(elementazie(sanitize(s)) for s in species))))
['Au', 'C', 'H', 'O']
```